# When does Cassandra DB index data after updating a column as secondary index

Tags: indexing, nosql, cassandra

I've a created a secondary index by using update column ... from cassandra-cli , then I tested by using commnand `get User where code = 'MX'` , code was the column I put as index,  this command just returns data inserted after index creation, but data before is not returned , I thought that previous data would be indexed too , anyone has a clue?
thanks in advance

Comment: What command did you use to update index ? when i update CF with index ,it has historical data too on querying

Comment: @Peter I was using Cassandra 1.0.8 and ran this command `update column family XXXX with comparator = 'UTF8Type' and column_metadata = [ ...... , {column_name : 'myColumnWithSecIndex',validation_class : UTF8Type,index_type : KEYS}];`

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686816/adding-secondary-index-on-cassandra-indexes-historical-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra, secondary index starts working only after it is being created.
Go through the SecondaryIndex class in  apache-cassandra library. It will help you in understanding.

Comment: can you respond to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686816/adding-secondary-index-on-cassandra-indexes-historical-data

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful [Cassandra secondary indexes](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes)